# Using different Font/Font size for Different Languages

Tags: java, fonts, internationalization

I work with a rather large Java GUI application (using Swing) with many different fonts and font sizes.

Recently we have added internationalization to our application, and as a result, for some languages, I am needing to change fonts so that different characters are able to be written (Chinese characters are not supported by many fonts) and so that all the characters fit on screen (the string in Chines may be longer/shorter than the string in English).

Is there a recommended way to make the fonts of my application more "modular", for lack of a better word?

Should I have some kind of static FontManager class that I use to get all fonts?

For instance, in my application I would get the font like this:

`Font mainScreenTitleFont = FontManager.getMainScreenTitleFont()`

and the method would look something like this (pseudo-code, obviously):

```
public static Font getMainScreenTitleFont(){
    if (language == Language.English)
        return new Font("Arial", 25);
    else if (language == Language.Chinese)
        return new Font("FangSong", 30); 
}
```

While this idea would accomplish what I am looking, I'm wondering if there is a better way to organize a system such as this?

Comment: Did you use JavaFx or Swing for your GUI ?

Comment: Sorry, I'll add that to the post. We use Swing, alongside some basic third party libraries like JFreeChart.

Comment: You can even embed your own font files in your jar, and use GraphicsEnvironment registerFont to register them. Maybe consider Right-To-Left (Arabic/Hebrew) at the same time. Or even accessibility (for the visually impaired). Declarative, say in property files would seem most flexible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you know of any websites that describe this practice more in depth?